# Git how to copy one branch to the master branch

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have a repository and I used to work with the master branch myself, now  we got a new employee, we created a new branch for him, and now his branch is stable, how can I copy its content to the master branch ?

I am using bitbucket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to do a `git merge`? The process of doing it is described [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging), but the tl;dr is `git checkout master && git merge his-branch`